# Auto-pickup of patrol mission? Auto-complete? What happened?

Tags: destiny

I was playing Destiny and I just finished a patrol mission, involving killing mobs to get drops, I forget exactly what it was but it was on Venus.

When I got the last drop I was running towards where the mobs spawned, they were coming out of a doorway when I killed them, and since my cat scratched at the door, I just ducked into the doorway and into the spawn area to have a safe place to stand still while I let my cat in and fed him.

While feeding him I heard the familiar voice of one of the patrol mission givers, and when I got back to the game I had a new patrol mission, involving gathering "Docking Caps" from fallen, and it was already at 33%.

How did this happen?

Did another player nearby pick up the mission and gather some of those items, and since I was close enough I got both the mission and the items?

I went outside the spawn area, and I can't see anyone close by, and suddenly the counter for the item is up to 67%. While I look around trying to figure out what is happening the mission completes.

What happened?

Note: I was not in a fireteam.

Comment: You was not in a fireteam before you went out, but may be not after that. What was your fireteam setting? If it was open or friends-only, then someone could join you, take the mission and go to other location so that you don't see him.

Answer (score 1):

I've definitely seen kills while playing alone from nearby players help me: I've seen them progress me towards killcounts, and I've seen them cause the generation of things I need to pick up.

Comment: Me too, I've had drops spawn from kills I didn't lay a finger on. Must be a proximity thing as I was right near them.